# How to snap legend to grid in Microsoft Excel 2010 graph

Tags: microsoft-excel

Any line graph in Microsoft Excel 2010 with grid lines turned on will serve as an example.

I have major grid lines on both axis. The legend overlays with the plot area.

**Question**:  Is there a way to snap the legend box to the grid?

I can manually try to adjust the legend to cover for example 3x2 grid-boxes. However, the alignment of the legend outline to the gridlines is generally poor.

*Note*: Yes, I can make plots using other software to achieve this effect. I'm curious if it can be done in Excel.

Comment: If anyone knows how to  or can figure out how - to do this, it's John Peltier. Check out his [web site](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: **No**.

This is a quote from [John Peltier on his website](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/legends-excel-charts-formats-size-shape-position/#comment-303961):

> There is no automatic way to align a legend with anything.
>   You can manually align it, and if the chart changes you are likely to have to realign it.
>   Click on the legend and drag it with the mouse so the top of the legend (or bottom) lines up with a gridline. Then click on one of the resizing handles on the perimiter of the legend, and stretch the legend so that the legend entries are aligned between gridlines.

Answer (score 1):

While technically Schorsch's answer is correct, there is a work-around to give you some control over snapping any element in Excel, `Page Layout > Align > Snap to Grid`.  Turning this on will allow you to snap to the spreadsheet's grid lines.

A practical application would include setting up a worksheet for display/output purposes.

1. Turn gridlines off, `View > Show > Gridlines` (uncheck).
2. Use the spreadsheet grid to create a layout grid for your objects, including Charts and their interior components (e.g. plot area, legend, titles, etc...).
3. Create your Chart and format to taste.
4. Turn on `Snap to Grid`.
5. Drag your Chart, and components, to their appropriate location on your spreadsheet page, and snap them in place.

Here's a sample with the Legend and Plot area snapped to the grid.

[image: Snap Legend]

This is also a good way to align data and its corresponding chart values.